# BFE are collinear. Find x . Can anyone do by Menelaus theorem? Or another type of Theorem. Please!

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If the roots of the equation $x ^ 2 + bx + 12 = 0$ are each $7$ units larger than the roots of $x ^ 2 + qx + 12 = 0$, then q is equal to:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you put the right question?

Anyway, $x^2+bx+12=0 \iff x = \frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-48}}{2}$

$y^2+qy+12=0 \iff y = \frac{-q\pm \sqrt{q^2-48}}{2}$

Now the roots are such that $x=y+7$.

$-b+ \sqrt{b^2-48} = -q+ \sqrt{q^2-48}+14$,

$-b- \sqrt{b^2-48} = -q- \sqrt{q^2-48}+14$

Adding these equations together gives

$-2b = -2q + 28$

So that $q = b +14 $.

Then we have $b^2 - 48 = q^2 - 48$.

I.e. $b^2 = q^2$.

Putting equation two into one by squaring:

$q^2 = b^2 + 28b + 196 \iff 28b = -196 \iff b = -7$.

Then $q = 7$.

Comment: Very good!  I put the right question yes!  I entered now wanting to send a geometry question, but I can not send images ...

Answer (score 0):

Or, simpler: if the roots of $x^2+qx+12=0$ are $a$ and $b$, then $x^2+qx+12 = (x-a)(x-b)$, hence $ab=12$ and $a+b = -q$. Since $a+7$ and $b+7$ are the roots of $x^2+bx+12=0$, it follows that $(a+7)(b+7) = 12 = ab$, which implies $7(a+b) + 49  = 0$. Hence $q = -(a+b) = 7$.